# How do slf4j Logger's debug/error/info methods internally work?

Tags: logging, slf4j

I tried to find the implementation of these methods but no luck. I want to know the implementation so that I can know how it handles String internally. I couldn't find anything anywhere. Possible that I was looking at wrong place. Please help with links/references. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the SLF4J docs](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html):

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks, such as java.util.logging, logback and log4j. SLF4J allows the end-user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time

So, the `Logger` *interface* is declared in the SLF4J library and the *implementation* of that interface (i.e. the "debug/error/info methods") is declared in whichever underlying logging framework you have chosen.

Examples of the implementations (or at least the entrypoints into the implementations) for common logging libraries:

- [Logback](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java)
- [java.util.logging](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-jdk14/src/main/java/org/slf4j/jul/JDK14LoggerAdapter.java)
- [log4j](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-slf4j-impl/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/slf4j/Log4jLogger.java)

Note: the relationship between *interface* and *implementation* is straightforward for Logback (`ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` implements `org.slf4j.Logger`) but for the other logging libraries there is typically an adapting layer which adapts the SLF4J interface to the implementation within each library. I have included links to some of those 'adapters' in the above list but a fuller set is available in the SLF4J GitHub repo: https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j.